# JPA with Hibernate 3 - ManyToMany-Stack overflow and Multiple bag errors

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa-2.0

I am facing issues while retrieving data for entities having bi-directional many-to-many relationship. If I use `List` for storing entities, I get unable to fetch multiple bags simultaneously error. If i change my code to use `Set`, I get stackoverflow error.

Details :

- Spring 3.0.3
- Hibernate-core : 3.5.1-Final
- Hibernate-annotations : 3.5.1-Final
- hibernate-common-annotations : 3.2.0-Final
- hibernate-entitymanager : 3.5.1-Final
- Mysql database
- Junit 4

User has Many Bank Accounts; Bank Account can have many users

User.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="user") 
private List<BankAccount> bankAccounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
```

BankAccount.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_bankaccount", 
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="bank_account_id"), 
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
)
private List<User> user = new ArrayList<User>();
```

DB Tables

```
Users
user_id PK

Bankaccount
bank_account_id PK

user_bankaccount
bank_account_id PK ( references bankaccount.bank_account_id )
user_id PK ( references user.user_id )
```

issues

1. when I try to get all the users data (`getAllUsers`) using a JUnit test case, I get unable to fetch multiple bags simultaneously error.
2. If I use `Set` and `HashSet` instead of List and `ArrayList` respectively, I get stackoverflow error.

Please help me and let me know if code is wrong or its a known hibernate issue with specific version of libs that I am using.

Answer (score 33):

I've faced the similar issue and the root cause is a Lombok generation code as Vjeetje mentioned above. My code uses the annotation @Data, which generates hashCode and ToString methods with cross-dependent fields and this structure leads to Hibernate stuck. So, one should care to avoid these infinite loop calls, in my case I just added the exclusion parameters, like @EqualsAndHashCode(exclude="dependent_list") and @ToString(exclude = "dependent_list"). It solves stack overflow issue.

Comment: An alternative is to annotate the fields with `@ToString.Exclude` and `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude`

Comment: @arnonuem Yes, but if Lombok version is 1.16.22 or higher

Comment: I tried using your mechanism, it failed. Sorry for a downvote.

Comment: @PratikGaurav at least you could share what exactly you had did

Comment: I tried these at the class level.

Comment: @PratikGaurav What tried? No example, no result, nothing.

Comment: I tried those annotations at class level, however as per your comment, I tried it again class level and problem got solved. Please don't be rude while communicating. Stackoverflow is community application, and we learn when we communicate. Also, I took back my downvote, hope it makes us both clear.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot map the many to many relationship on both of the lists, hibernate will then try to fetch a collection for every nested element i.e. every user in the users list has a list of bank accounts which have a list of users... . think of it of a never ending recursion.

Comment: Hi Noam thanks for your reply. But dont we need Collection on both sides since its a many-to-many relationship ?

Comment: in order for hibernate to map the collections only one side is required. from the hibernate annotaion docs: "As seen previously, the other side don't have to (must not) describe the physical mapping: a simple mappedBy argument containing the owner side property name bind the two."

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by removing references of other entity from toString() method. i.e removed references of BankAccount from User object's toString method and vice versa. I also removed fetch=fetchType.EAGER from all the entities.However, i thought that hibernate was able to detect such a cyclic dependency and not throw stackoverflow exception.

Answer (score 2):

(Let's leave the `fetch` attribute aside for now). Your mapping is perfectly valid and is the right way to map a bidirectional many-to-many relationship. From the JPA 2.0 specification:

> #### 2.10.4 Bidirectional ManyToMany Relationships
>
> ...
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> @Entity
> public class Project {
>     private Collection<Employee> employees;
>
>     @ManyToMany
>     public Collection<Employee> getEmployees() {
>         return employees;
>     }
>
>     public void setEmployees(Collection<Employee> employees) {
>         this.employees = employees;
>     }
>     ...
> }
>
> @Entity
> public class Employee {
>     private Collection<Project> projects;
>
>     @ManyToMany(mappedBy="employees")
>     public Collection<Project> getProjects() {
>         return projects;
>     }
>     public void setProjects(Collection<Project> projects) {
>         this.projects = projects;
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> In this example:
>
> - Entity `Project` references a collection of Entity `Employee`.
> - Entity `Employee` references a collection of Entity `Project`.
> - Entity `Project` is the owner of the relationship.
>
> ...

That being said, I'm unsure of the behavior **when using `EAGER` fetching on both sides** (will it lead to an infinite cycle?), the JPA specification is pretty blurry about this and I can't find any clear mention that it is forbidden. But I bet that it's part of the problem.

But in the particular case of Hibernate, I'd expect Hibernate to be able to handle cycles as mentioned in [this comment](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4147?focusedCommentId=25378&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_25378) from Emmanuel Bernard:

> LAZY or EAGER should be orthogonal to an infinite loop issue in the codebase. Hibernate knows how to handle cyclic graphs

Funnily enough, I've answered [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978733/hibernate-manytomany-bidirectional-eager-fetching/3978903#3978903) recently (very close problem). **Maybe** an hint that something is wrong in Hibernate (my understanding of the above comment is that using EAGER fetching on both sides should work).

I'll thus conclude my answer in the same way: **if you can provide a test case allowing to reproduce the problem**, open a Jira issue.

Comment: I have added JIRA for this issue alongwith complete source code http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5691

Comment: I had a very similar issue using Lombok's ToSring annotation on a many-to-many relationship between two entities. Solution: use the exclude attribute of the ToString annotation. Anyway, Hibernate can work fine with a many-to-many relationship where both sides are fetched eagerly.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue.

The problem was with my @Data annotation from the lombok library.

To fix it, I replaced @Data with @Getter, @Setter. And defined a custom toString() method on the class.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem,

Classes go in recursion.

The solution : Remove the default toString() and hashCode() method, from Lombok and how to remove it.

Add two annotations to mention the customization.

```
@ToString(exclude = "components")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "components")
```

Complete example.

```
package com.oracle.dto2;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
@ToString(exclude = "components")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "components")
public class Device {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,generator = "ds")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ds",sequenceName = "dev_seq",allocationSize = 1,initialValue = 1)
    @Column(name = "device_Id",updatable = false,nullable = false)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Integer deviceId;
    @OneToMany
    List<Component> components;
}
```

```
package com.oracle.dto2;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
public class Component {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,generator = "cs")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "cs",sequenceName = "comp_seq",allocationSize = 1,initialValue = 1)
    @Column(name = "component_Id",updatable = false,nullable = false)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long componentId;
    @Column(name="component_price",nullable = false)
    private Double price;
    @Column(name="component_manufacturer",nullable = true)
    private String manufacturer;
}
```